# How to prevent grunt process exit?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I want to use `fs.watch` in my plugin. but the grunt process will exit after run task and file watch was stoped. How do I keep the file watch task working ?  I can't find out similar code in `grunt-contrib-watch`

the code like this (a part of my plugin):

```
      grunt.registerTask('prevent', 
         'watch file and prevent process exit',
         function(grunt){
           _fs = require('fs')
          _fs.watch(process.cwd(), function(event, filename){
            console.log(event, filename)
          }
     }
```

Thanks for your input !

Comment: Why not use `grunt-contrib-watch` to do the watching, and let it call your task?

Comment: @merlin yes，it's good idea. but i want to know how to do it

Comment: Are you Chinese? Than we don't have to talk in english. We can chat using QQ.That will help us communicate mush faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Grunt to wait, you can call `this.async` inside your task function:

```
grunt.registerTask('prevent', 'watch file and prevent process exit',
    function (grunt) {
        var done = this.async(),
            _fs = require('fs');

        _fs.watch(process.cwd(), function (event, filename) {
            console.log(event, filename)
        });
    });
```

See the `this.async` doc [here](http://gruntjs.com/api/inside-tasks#this.async).